# Do you know a good android rendering engine?

Tags: android, rendering-engine

What is a rendering engine? Is there any for Android?

Answer (score 15):

This a list of rendering engines for Android. Some of them are `C++ based` therefore you're able to use C++. Some of them are Java-Based which allows you to draw graphics without the need to use Android-NDK.

**Alien3D**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Apache License 2.0 (Open Source)
- Language: Java

**Antiryad Gx**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Beginner
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C, C++

**Ardor3D**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: libpng/zlib license (Open Source)
- Language: Java

**BatteryTech**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Indi:$199.95, Commercial:$799.95
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C++

**Catcake**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: MIT License (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**Corona SDK**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Trial is Free, Indie $199/Year, Pro is $349/Year
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: Lua

**Dwarf FW**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: MIT License (Open Source)
- Language: Java

**DX Studio**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Freeware Edition:Free, Commercial Pro:Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C++, C# or VB.Net

**EDGELIB**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free, 1 Developer: €5,000
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C++

**Esenthel Engine**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free, Personal:$150, Company:$750, Pro:$4000, Ultimate, Non-Game:$250/year
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C++

**Forget 3D Game Engine**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: GNU GPL v2 (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**GameKit**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: MIT License (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**GamePlay**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Apache 2.0 license (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**IwGame Engine**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free although requires the Marmalade SDK
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**jMonkeyEngine**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: BSD (Open Source)    Language: Java

**jPCT-AE**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: jPCT-AE license (Open Source)
- Language: Java

**libGDX**

- Platforms:Android HTML5
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Apache License 2.0 (Open Source)
- Language: Java

**Linderdaum Engine**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free/?
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Non-commercial/Commercial usage (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**Marmalade**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Trial:Free, Basic:$149, Standard:$499
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C++

**Matali Physics Engine**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Non-Commercial, Commercial
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C#

**min3D**

- Platforms:Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: MIT License (Open Source)
- Language: Java

**MoSync Mobile**

- Platforms:iPhone Android HTML5
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free, Basic Pro: 199 Euro, Gold Pro: 2999 Euro
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: GNU GPL v2 (Open Source)
- Language: C, C++

**NME**

- Platforms:iPhone Android HTML5
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: MIT License (Open Source)
- Language: Haxe

**openFrameworks**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: MIT License (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**Orx**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: zlib license (Open Source)
- Language: C, C++, Objective-C

**Proton SDK**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Free
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: BSD style with attribution required (Open Source)
- Language: C++

**ShiVa3D Game Engine**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Web:Free, Advanced:$1000, Basic:$200, Educational:$670
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: Lua

**SIO2 Engine**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 2D 3D
- Price: Trial is Free, Win/Mac:$199.99, Android/iOS:$399.99
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C++

**UNIGINE Engine**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Case-by-case (about $30,000 USD/project)
- Skill: Beginner
- License: Proprietary
- Language: C++

**Unity3D**

- Platforms:iPhone Android
- Orientations: 3D
- Price: Unity:Free, Unity Pro:$1500
- Skill: Intermediate
- License: Proprietary
- Language: .NET (Mono)

For more info you can check:
[3D Android Game Engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/android/3d_game_engines)

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to Stack Overflow! It's perfectly okay to answer old questions. Why? There is *one* original poster, but this post has been viewed 922 times, possibly by others with the same problem! The goal is to be useful to future visitors as well. ;) One way you can solidify this is to first, edit out the part about the question being 2 years old; it's not relevant to the problem, and second, list the rendering engines from the link. If the link were to ever break, your answer would still be useful if the items are listed in the answer. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different methods for rendering objects to the screen in Android: [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and [`OpenGL`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

I suggest you check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) that explains your various options as to how to draw to the screen. `OpenGl` is more powerful, but more difficult to use. You may also want to check out [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) which allows you to use the built-in Android `Drawable` to render to the screen.

It depends on if you want to use high-end 3D performace in the end. If you do then you have to use `OpenGL`, otherwise you have a choice between using a `SurfaceView` or `OpenGL`.

Comment: Then, OpenGL is a rendering engine for Android, isn't it?

Comment: Amongst other things, its not just for Android